# How to implement "first" for ArrowApply?

Tags: haskell, arrows

In ["Programming with Arrows"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf), Hughes asserts

> First of all, note that both first and left are easy to implement in terms
>   of app  (the details are left as an exercise).

From Control.Arrow, `left` can be implemented as:

```
leftApp :: ArrowApply a => a b c -> a (Either b d) (Either c d)
leftApp f = arr ((\b -> (arr (\() -> b) >>> f >>> arr Left, ())) |||
                 (\d -> (arr (\() -> d) >>> arr Right, ()))) >>> app
```

How do I implement `first` with just `arr`, `>>>`, and `app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, but I would be very interested if there is a simpler solution

```
firstApp :: ArrowApply cat => cat t t1 -> cat (t, t2) (t1, t2)
firstApp f = arr (\(x, y) -> (arr (\() -> (f, x))) >>>
                             app >>>
                             (arr (\v -> (v, y)))) >>>
             arr (\v -> (v, ())) >>>
             app
```

Comment: For me it's not that easy to implement both functions through app. :) I tried hard but did not manage to find any alternative.